# GET request missing'G'

Tags: spring-boot

error:{org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'ET' not supported}

The first time enter the page interface, there is no error, and the secondary page is saved and returned, and an interface reports an error

my controller:
@GetMapping(value = "/queryFinancialByName")
public Result queryFinancialByName(String orgName, HttpServletRequest request){}

Comment: could you please provide runnable code ? Enough to understand what is going on

Comment: '@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/orgManage")
public class OrgManageController {
 @GetMapping(value = "/queryFinancialByName")
    public void queryFinancialByName(String orgName, HttpServletRequest request) {
        //do something  
    }
}'

Comment: I mean a runnable code from application too, better a github example

Comment: At first glance the problem resides on client-side, not on server (spring-boot) side: The client issues a request with an invalid method.